# How to change the width of the dashed line in table?

Tags: tables, arydshln

I need to draw several **dashed lines of different width in one table**, but I don't know how to make it.

I know how to draw a single dashed line using package `arydshln`, but how to set the width of these dashed lines?
`\setheight\arrayrulewidth{1pt}` only works for a whole table, not for specific single line.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
% \setheight\arrayrulewidth{1pt} % works for the whole table
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hdashline % need set to 0.8pt
  a & b\\
  \hdashline % need set to 0.6pt
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### My solution

I use package `ehhline` and `dashrule` to get what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{ehhline}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\newcommand\cdl[2]{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{#1}{\hdashrule{0.4mm}{#2}{0.2mm 0.2mm}}}\hfil}
\newcommand\crs[2]{\leaders\hbox{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{0.1pt}{#2}}}\hfil}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hhline{
  !{\cdl{red}{1pt}}
  !{\crs{red}{1pt}}
}
test some thing & test\\
\hhline{
  !{\cdl{blue}{4pt}}
  !{\crs{blue}{4pt}}
}
  test some thing & test\\
\hhline{
  !{\cdl{blue}{4pt}}
  !{\crs{blue}{4pt}}
}
  test some thing & test\\
\hhline{
  !{\cdl{blue}{4pt}}
  !{\crs{blue}{4pt}}
}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: dashed line]

#### Remain solved

But there is another problem: how to draw **vertical dashed line** of different color and width

Comment: There are two lengths used, \dashlinesash and \dsahlinegap (page 3 of manual).  Alas, they can only be set once.

Comment: Leaders can be used in vertical mode too (with \vfill).  See page 225 of the TeXbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0 of 2020-05-08), you can draw whatever rule you want with Tikz by using the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix` under the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {  
    dashed 1/.style = 
      {
        red ,
        dash pattern = on 2pt off 3pt ,
        line width = 1 pt 
      } ,
    dashed 2/.style = 
      {
        blue ,
        dash pattern = on 1pt off 1pt ,
        line width = 2pt 
      }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{|ccc|}
\hline
text text & text text & text text \\
text text & text text & text text \\
text text & text text & text text \\
text text & text text & text text \\
text text & text text & text text \\
\hline
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed 1] (1-|2) -- (6-|2) (2-|1) -- (2-|4) ;
\draw [dashed 2] (1-|3) -- (6-|3) (4-|1) -- (4-|4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

With recent versions of `nicematrix` (6.12 of 2022-07-28), it's also possible to define letters (for the vertical rules) and commands (for the horizontal rules) to draw rules with whatever Tikz style we want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions
  {  
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = I , 
        command = DashedLine ,
        tikz = 
          {
            red ,
            dash pattern = on 2pt off 3pt ,
            line width = 1 pt 
          } ,
        total-width = 1 pt % space reserved for the rule
      } ,
    custom-line = 
      {
        letter = J ,
        command = DashedLineBis ,
        tikz = 
          {
            blue ,
            dash pattern = on 1pt off 1pt ,
            line width = 2pt 
          } ,
        total-width = 2 pt 
      }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{|cIcJc|}
\hline
text text & text text & text text \\
\DashedLine
text text & text text & text text \\
text text & text text & text text \\
\DashedLineBis
text text & text text & text text \\
text text & text text & text text \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with leaders, so the only way I could get this to work was to first measure the width of the tabular.  To this end I created the `mytabular` environment.

I did not implement double dashed lines or dashed `\cline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand{\dashline}[3]% #1 = dash, #2 = spacing, #3 = height
{\noalign{\hbox to \wd\mybox{\leaders\hbox to #2{\hss\rule{#1}{#3}\hss}\hfill}}}

\newcommand{\gobbleline}[3]{\noalign{\hrule}}

\NewEnviron{mytabular}[1]% #1 = tabular parameters
{\savebox{\mybox}{\let\dashline=\gobbleline% disable \dashline
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \BODY
  \end{tabular}}% measure width
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \BODY
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}{cc}
\dashline{0.8pt}{4pt}{1pt}
  a & b \\
\dashline{0.4pt}{4pt}{0.5pt}
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, one can redefine the tabular environment, but it will take twice as long as the old one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newcommand{\dashline}[3]% #1 = dash, #2 = spacing, #3 = height
{\noalign{\hbox to \wd\mybox{\leaders\hbox to #2{\hss\rule{#1}{#3}\hss}\hfill}}}

\newcommand{\gobbleline}[3]{\noalign{\hrule}}

\let\oldtabular=\tabular
\let\oldendtabular=\endtabular

\RenewEnviron{tabular}[1]% #1 = normal tabular parameters
{\savebox{\mybox}{\let\dashline=\gobbleline% disable \dashline
  \oldtabular{#1}
    \BODY
  \oldendtabular}% measure width
  \oldtabular{#1}
    \BODY
  \oldendtabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\dashline{0.8pt}{4pt}{1pt}
  a & b \\
\dashline{0.4pt}{4pt}{0.5pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your anser works but is a little tricky for me, I need some time to understand how it works. But I find another possible way with a small problem. I have edit my question.

Comment: I solved the problem of horizonal dashed line, but how to draw vertical dashed lines.